# Unmarshal different JSON messages with a common type field in go

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have implemented a chat server in golang based on the TCP protocol. Client to Server communication uses JSON and uses a simple protocol which separates the messages by a newline (\n). There are several valid message types which contain different fields but all of them contain a common type field which declares the type of the message. Some examples are shown below.

```json
{"type" : "newidentity", "identity" : "Adel"}
{"type" : "newidentity", "approved" : "true"}
{
"type" : "roomlist",
"rooms" : ["MainHall-s1", "MainHall-s2", "jokes"]
}
{"type" : "createroom", "roomid" : "jokes"}
```

The part of the section for incoming message handling at the server is shown below (Not the actual code just an example).

```golang
func handleConnection(c net.Conn) {
    fmt.Print(".")
    for {
        netData, err := bufio.NewReader(c).ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        res, err := json.Marshal(IdentitySuccess{MessageType: "newidentity", Approved: "approved"})
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
        }
        c.Write([]byte(string(res) + "\n"))
    }
    c.Close()
}
```

So I want to create structs from these JSON messages (netData in the above code snippet) and use those structs in the application. What is the easiest way to unmarshal those different JSON strings with the common field and get structs from those ? So ideally I want something like a function where it outputs the type and the struct of the received JSON text.

Comment: Maybe you need to use `map[string]string`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating different structs I would suggest you to use one struct and unmarshal the values into it and after unmarshalling the values you can write the custom handlers on the basis of your requirements.

Also in the example above you are not separating each message by `\n`. But if you have one message in one line then what you can  do is something is like this.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type IdentitySuccess struct {
    Type     string   `json:"type"`
    Identity string   `json:"identity,omitempty"`
    Approved string   `json:"approved,omitempty"`
    Rooms    []string `json:"rooms,omitempty"`
    Roomid   string   `json:"roomid,omitempty"`
}

func Process(data []byte) (IdentitySuccess, error) {
    var r IdentitySuccess
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &r)
    return r, err
}

func main() {
    jsonData :=
        `{"type" : "newidentity", "identity" : "Adel"}
         {"type" : "newidentity", "approved" : "true"}
         {"type" : "roomlist","rooms" : ["MainHall-s1", "MainHall-s2", "jokes"]}
         {"type" : "createroom", "roomid" : "jokes"}`
    // Because you are taking \n as a seperator and all of this is coming in one response
    jsons := strings.Split(jsonData, "\n")
    for _, json := range jsons {
        identity, err := Process([]byte(json))
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        // Custom handlers will be applied here on the basis of the struct values
        if identity.Type == "newidentity" && identity.Identity != "" {
            fmt.Printf("Got type= %v, with identity = %v\n", identity.Type, identity.Identity)
        } else if identity.Type == "newidentity" && identity.Approved != "" {
            fmt.Printf("Got type= %v, with approved status = %v\n", identity.Type, identity.Approved)
        } else if identity.Type == "roomlist" {
            fmt.Printf("Got type= %v, with rooms = %v\n", identity.Type, identity.Rooms)
        } else if identity.Type == "createroom" {
            fmt.Printf("Got type= %v, with roomid = %v\n", identity.Type, identity.Roomid)
        }
    }

}
```

The output for the above sniipet would be this

```
Got type= newidentity, with identity = Adel
Got type= newidentity, with approved status = true
Got type= roomlist, with rooms = [MainHall-s1 MainHall-s2 jokes]
Got type=createroom, with roomid = jokes
```

Below is the playground link too

https://play.golang.org/p/eFPj3z-x39-